# Current object in rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If i have a controller called Ece. It stores many courses. Now if a user is on a show page of a particular course. How would i know which Ece object's show page is displayed. That is i want to access the current Ece object. Ultimately i want to do this to the current ece object

```
@code = current_ece.course_code # assuming current_ece means the current object
```

I want to use @code for other purposes.

Where course_code is one of the columns. I want to do this only on the current Ece object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in your `show` action you will grab the current object and put it in an instance variable:

```
def show
  @ece = Ece.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :json => @ece }
  end
end
```

Then you can just use `@ece` inside your view. Read the [Getting Started with Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) [Rails 3/edge link] guide for more information.